# Fluorine request not being made in some IE versions

Tags: actionscript-3, internet-explorer-8, amf, fluorinefx

We have a really strange problem with a piece of Fluorine integration we've built.

We have a form with a Captcha on it; the Captcha image is populated from a .Net/AMF webservice inventively titled `GetCaptchaImage.ashx` and can be reloaded from a text hyperlink within the Flash.

In some versions of IE (particularly IE8, but it may also be others), *irrespective of [IE version emulation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [wmode](/questions/886864)*, clicking the text link causes the HTTP call to our Fluorine gateway successfully to be made, but the call to the webservice does not follow it. Inspecting the HTTP transactions with [Microsoft Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com), we see:

```
POST http://www.domain.com/gateway.aspx
200 OK (application/x-amf)
```

and nothing else, whereas in any other browser we see:

```
POST http://www.domain.com/gateway.aspx
200 OK (application/x-amf)
GET http://www.domain.com/GetCaptchaImage.ashx
200 OK (image/gif)
```

The code that makes the call appears to be inherited, without any override, from `org.osflash.signals.Signal.dispatch`, so I can't see why it wouldn't Just Bloody Work™. The actual method call reads:

```
private function getNewCaptcha(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    getCaptchaAgain.dispatch();
    trace("Captcha button click");
    GlobalDebugger.log(this, "Captcha button click!");
}
```

where the only other mentions of `getCaptchaAgain` in the entire codebase are:

```
public var getCaptchaAgain:Signal = new Signal();
```

and

```
compForm.getCaptchaAgain.add(getTheCaptchaAgain);
```

and the only other occurrence of `getNewCaptcha` is the line:

```
_cantReadCaptchaButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getNewCaptcha);
```

**Edit:** [Juan Pablo Califano](/users/24170) pointed out I'd failed to notice that there was a reference to `getTheCaptchaAgain`, which I'd misread as `getCaptchaAgain`. It is defined as

```
private function getTheCaptchaAgain():void
{
    captchaSignal.dispatch();
}
```

and is only called from `onFormResponse`, where it is uninteresting. `captchaSignal` is defined in

```
public class CompetitionFormMediator extends AbstractFactoryAccessorMediator
{
    [Inject]
    public var captchaSignal:CaptchaSignal;
    // ...
}
```

`CaptchaSignal` extends `org.osflash.signals.Signal` and is uninteresting but is called in a line reading:

```
signalCommandMap.mapSignalClass(CaptchaSignal, CaptchaCommand);
```

`CaptchaCommand` extends `SignalCommand` and ends up inside `flash.events.EventDispatcher` calling

```
var callFunction:Function = serviceHub.call;
callFunction.apply(serviceHub, collectArgs);
```

where `collectArgs` is an `Array` of arguments that don't offer any clues.

**End edit**

Does anyone have any idea why on earth that second call wouldn't be making it to the webserver? I can't see why the Flash wouldn't be issuing the HTTP `GET` but, equally, I can't think of any reason why a browser (let alone just this browser) would be suppressing it. I'm not a Flash developer (I run the .Net team here), but I can't see anything odd there and neither I nor the Flash team (including the developer who built the code) can think of any reason why this might be happening.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Does the `getTheCaptchaAgain` method get called? What's the code on that method? (I don't have much experience with Signals, but I understand it's a framework for event dispatching, so the code that makes the actual http request must be on `getTheCaptchaAgain` or some other function called from there).

Comment: `getCaptchaAgain` is the button on the form that users click to reload the Captcha; I believe the functionality itself is handled by the Fluorine framework, but the initial HTTP call to the gateway gets called, we just can't see why the specific webservice doesn't then get called subsequently.

Comment: It seems to me that `getCaptchaAgain` is a dispatcher and `getTheCaptchaAgain` is a listener registered to it (according to this line: `compForm.getCaptchaAgain.add(getTheCaptchaAgain);`. So, the flow seems to be: `_cantReadCaptchaButton` gets clicked, the mouse event is captured by `getNewCaptcha`; `getCaptchaAgain.dispatch()` is called, causing getCaptchaAgain to notify its listeners, one which is presumably `getTheCaptchaAgain`. That's why I mentioned the `getTheCaptchaAgain` method (not the `getCaptchaAgain` object). Again, I'm not familiar with Floruine or Signals so I could be wrong.

Comment: I'd failed to notice that `getCaptchaAgain` and `getTheCaptchaAgain` were two different things (I'll have words about naming conventions with the ActionScript guys ;o)  I've edited the question to provide a bit more context.

Comment: Have you log4Net enabled on the server? You could log FluorineFx's actions into a txt file or into a database. That could maybe help you see why GetCaptchaImage.ashx is sometimes not called at all.

Comment: @Owen Blacker. Yes, the naming scheme is not the brightest. I see two main points of failure. First, the "order" (command, event, whatever) doesn't make it to the code that does the actual request (the listener has been removed somewhere, there's a weak ref and the IE version of the player is more aggresive GC-wise, etc). Or there's a problem in the code that issues the HTTP request.

Comment: (cont...) What I'd do at this point is hooking up the debugger and placing a few breakpoints to see what's actually going on (or at least narrowing down the problem). I don't know if that's available to you (or any of your AS guys), though. If anything else, tracing could help to see what code gets executed. Once you know if it's a networking problem or an internal problem regarding how the app modules communicate, you'll have a better chance to find the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all that, it looks like it was a problem elsewhere in the Flash, and the handler in question (`/GetCaptchaImage.ashx`) being considered unchanged by the browser.

So we've solved the problem with caching settings, rather than needing to do much else.

Thanks for your help everyone, particularly [Juan Pablo](/users/24170)!